# My state changes but the URL does not get updated

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a nested state structure in my angular app using ui-router and I have this problem:

My state changes but the URL does not get updated to the child's state URL.

Previously, I had forgotten to include the `<div ui-view></div>` on the parent view and the URL got updated, but my child controller was not called.

Now that I have included the missing `ui-view`, the URL does not change, but everything else seems to work great (apart from the back/forward navigation on the browser of course...).
I have tried using `{ location: true }` :

```
$state.go('parent.child', $stateParams, { location: true });
```

..but it didn't help.

Any ideas anybody?

Comment: try `$state.go('parent.child', $stateParams, { location: true, reload: true });`

Comment: Adding the `{ location: true, reload: true }` put my app in an infinite loop that reveled that I was accidentally changing the state when the child controller was called. I don't know why the URL and the state went out of sync eventually, but that was causing the problem. Thanks! :)